# Hasura GraphQL query : where clause with value from related entity

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, hasura

I recently started using GraphQL through a Hasura layer on top of a PostgreSQL DB. I am having troubles implementing a basic query.

Here are my entities :

**article :**

- articleId
- content
- publishedDate
- categoryId

**category :**

- categoryId
- name
- createdDate

What I am trying to achieve, in English, is the following : **get the articles that were published in the first 3 days following the creation of their related category.**

In pseudo-SQL, I would do something similar to this :

```
SELECT Article.content, Category.name
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Category ON Article.categoryId = Category.categoryId
WHERE Article.publishedDate < Category.createdDate + 3 days
```

Now as a GraphQL query, I tried something similar to this :

```
query MyQuery {
    articles(where: {publishedDate: {_lt: category.createdDate + 3 days}}) {
        content
        category {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not recognise the “category.createdDate” in the where clause. I tried multiple variations, including aliases, with no success.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't think you can reference other fields in queries. I think you would have to create a view where you either filter for the rows you want in the first place _or_ you could simply select the difference as a row and then query for that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding of the Hasura docs, there is no way to reference a field within a query like you can do in SQL. But that does not mean, you can't do, what you are trying to do. There are three ways of achieving the result that you want:

#### 1. Create a filtered view

```sql
CREATE VIEW earliest_articles AS
SELECT Article.*
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Category ON Article.categoryId = Category.categoryId
WHERE Article.publishedDate < Category.createdDate + 3 days
```

This view should now become available as a query. [Docs for views are here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/views.html#creating-views).

#### 2. Create a view with a new field

```sql
CREATE VIEW articles_with_creation_span AS
SELECT
  Article.*,
  (Article.publishedDate - Category.createdDate) AS since_category_creation
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Category ON Article.categoryId = Category.categoryId
```

Now you can again query this view and use a filter query on the extra field. This solution is useful if you want to vary the amount of time, that you want to query for. The downside is, that there are now two different `article` types, it might make sense to hide the regular articles query then.

#### 3. Use a *computed field*

You can also define computed fields in Hasura. These fields are not only included in the output object type of the corresponding GraphQL type, but they can also be used for querying. Refer to [the docs](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/computed-fields.html#scalar-computed-fields) on how to create a computed field. Here you can again, calculate the difference and then use some kind of comparison operator (`<`) to check if this time is smaller than `'3 days'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very clear and well explained. I was hoping for a purely GraphQL solution, but it seems like it is not possible with that Hasura setup. Thanks again.